# currency rates from yahoo finance limitations

Tags: yahoo-finance

I'm trying to write a script that would download currency rates from yahoo finance. The problem is ... i can't find any information on the limitations of this service. Especially i'm interested in how often i can query yahoo finance to access the quotes.csv file. Would yahoo kill my script if i executed it periodically every minute or so? Does anyone know where i could find some official yahoo information of things like that? I've been searching for hours, but it's either well hidden or it's just hiding in plain sight and i don't see it...

Answer (score 1):

Usually its against the TOS of the website. However if you want to collect data that way on a small scale it is fairly trivial. I have mined yahoo finance in the past and have never been turned off. Don't hammer the site...space out your requests. If you want to be even more clever about it script a web browser to do it for you. The page requests will then look identical.